# Cloud Foundry Scaling

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a few basic questions around CF autoscaling that I am hoping someone can help with.

It appears that non-commercial Cloud Foundry does not provide auto-scaling out of the box. I realise I can use 'cf scale', but can CF emit custom events so that I can trigger cf scale?

I have seen another post that talks about auto-scaling by setting up an instance of an auto-scaler and binding the auto-scaler with the LRP, but I have seen other articles saying that there is no auto-scale capability in non-commercial CF.

And if I am deploying microservices, and those services use downstream services that I have not written, I would be relying on those downstream services scaling appropriately too?

And I assume I would be prevented from scaling beyond the limit of the 'space' anyway?

I see that Kubernetes provides auto-scaling, so I am thinking that perhaps that is a more scalable solution.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App autoscaling is under development at https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/app-autoscaler. I believe it's usable already.
It only scales your app, not downstream services (unless they are deployed as CF apps as well in your account).
The app auto-scaler does what `cf scale` would do, but automatically, so is still bound to the quota you have configured for your space and org.

Answer (score 0):

you can find more resources regarding autoscaling here:

https://docs.run.pivotal.io/appsman-services/autoscaler/using-autoscaler.html

to scale an app you may use the command:

```
cf scale appname -m 512M
```

where appname is name of your application. Above command will scale the app to 512 MBs..